# How can i get navigation sub category/collection in shopify using graphQL

Tags: collections, shopify, categories

I am using this

{

menu(handle:"Life")
{
id
items{
id
title
type
}

}
}

but it is working only for parent collection or single collection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This query should return the menu items within a parent menu and the parent menu.

```
{
  menu(handle:"main-menu"){
     items{
      id
      tags
      title
      url
      items{
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```